# Indexing data from CSV file in Apache Solr

Tags: java, php, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have followed the tutorials given in below link

[Indexing csv file in solr](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/apache-solr-tutorial-beginners/)

I have configured solr server in my local and

But when i try to post csv file using the below command

```
java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/jcg/update -jar post.jar  books.csv
```

I am getting below error response in command prompt

Any one help why i am getting the error response

**Error:**

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">111</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str></lst><str name=
"msg">ERROR: [doc=0553573403] unknown field 'cat'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Whats the data of csv file? do you have the schema.xml which had the field named cat? like <field name="cat" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you're following is quite old, so if you want follow the tutorial there are two options:

1. the tutorial you're following misses the creation of Schema configuration in `jcg` collection. In this case you should fix your `managed-schema` file to `jcg` configuration taking care to add the following fields as suggested in the Tutorial, then reload the configuration (or restart Solr). At this point the "Indexing the Data" step should work correctly.

```xml
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
 <!-- Fields added for books.csv load-->
 <field name="cat" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="price" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

2. You have correctly added schema and fields but not reloaded the configuration, but not reloaded the collection. So just reload the configuration (or restart Solr) and continue with the tutorial.

On the other hand, if you're using an earlier version of Solr (6.4) I suggest to delete `jcg` collection and create it again:

```
bin/solr delete -c jcg
bin/solr create -c jcg -d ./server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs
```